# Let P be a singly linked list. Let Q be the pointer to an intermediate node x in the list.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let P be a singly linked list. Let Q be the pointer to an intermediate node x in the list. What is the worst-case time complexity of the best-known algorithm to delete the node x from the list ?

A. O(n) 
B. O(log2n)
C. O(logn)
D. O(1)

My approach:
Since Q is pointing to node X, it can de done in O(1) time..

Algo:

Q→data=Q→next→data; // Copy the value of next node into Q.

del=Q→next; // take another pointer variable pointing to next node of Q.

Q→next=Q→next→next;

free(del);

Correct Answer: A

Is it true as per question?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Q→data=Q→next→data; // Copy the value of next node into Q.

del=Q→next; // take another pointer variable pointing to next node of Q.

Q→next=Q→next→next;

free(del);

Correct Answer: A

Is it true as per question?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is linear time complexity since you only have a pointer to intermediate element x. Now from x you can reach its successor, but not its predecessor. What needs to be done is:

Access element x

Save the pointer to its sucessor q

Iterate from beginning of the list to the predecessor of x ( here is where linear complexity comes from )

Let predecessor of x be y

Delete x

Set sucessor of y to be q.

The end.